# How do I get the tests to pass in section 8.1.1?

Tags: railstutorial.org

My test in [section 8.1.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-sessions_controller) is failing, when the tutorial says it should pass. There is a similar, closed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142550/ruby-on-rails-michael-hartl-failing-test-8-1-1) . My question is different than that one because my test produces 17 failures instead of 15.

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication signin page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signin_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x529d880>:0x52a3970>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication signin page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signin_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x529d880>:0x48f2238>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Static pages Home page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_1:0x44ae8e0>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Static pages Home page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_1:0x42bb2c0>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Static pages Home page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_1:0x42f6120>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Static pages Help page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit help_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4c59f00>:0x4c62d08>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) Static pages Help page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit help_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4c59f00>:0x311a0c0>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) Static pages About page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit about_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4c59f00>:0x3fdc578>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  9) Static pages About page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit about_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4c59f00>:0x47fdac8>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  10) Static pages Contact page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit contact_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4c59f00>:0x3ddd330>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  11) Static pages Contact page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit contact_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4c59f00>:0x4cea548>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  12) User pages profile page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4e20a00>:0x4e2a1c8>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  13) User pages profile page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4e20a00>:0x3fdf0e0>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  14) User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4e20a00>:0x48f8a60>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  15) User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4e20a00>:0x4ccddd8>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  16) User pages signup with invalid information should not create a user
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4e20a00>:0x4dffdf0>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  17) User pages signup with valid information should create a user
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x4e20a00>:0x3113700>
     # ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___509603306_33401520'
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___981332443_30718356'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 7.96 seconds
37 examples, 17 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:10 # Authentication signin page 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:11 # Authentication signin page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:10 # Static pages Home page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:11 # Static pages Home page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:12 # Static pages Home page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:18 # Static pages Help page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19 # Static pages Help page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:25 # Static pages About page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26 # Static pages About page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:32 # Static pages Contact page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:33 # Static pages Contact page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11 # User pages profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12 # User pages profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:18 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:19 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:29 # User pages signup with invalid information should not create a user
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:42 # User pages signup with valid information should create a user
```

Comment: As the errors make very obvious, I had somehow removed the root path from my routes.rb file. Once I put the following line back in, all the tests passed:

    `root to: 'static_pages#home'`

Comment: That's great that you were able to solve your problem.  If you want, you can put your answer in to an "answer" below and mark it as solved to let everyone else know that this issue doesn't require assistance anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the errors make very obvious, I had somehow removed the root path from my routes.rb file. Once I put the following line back in, all the tests passed:

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'
```